# How to use mapIndexed or similar to return specific elements from list

Tags: list, kotlin

I created a simple memory game but I'm having an issue with one of the functions. Here, I want to return a simple List that would contain the flipped correct guesses but I can't figure out how to do that and had to reassign a variable to be a MutableList since I am not supposed to create new variables in the code, or edit the main and play functions which I had to do to add the parameter I changed in turnPlaces(). However, this isn't the ideal solution, and I want to use a function like .mapIndexed() to do this but can't get it to work.

The game prints out a pair of these symbols "#%XO&" and shuffles them and the user has to guess the correct position for 2 pairs, so say the user types in 0 and 9, and correctly guesses a pair: X________X

I'm only gonna leave the main, play and turnPlaces(the one that's giving me this issue) functions below, the one I'm having issues with being at the bottom. Thanks for any help in advance!

```
fun main() {
    val pairs = (SYMBOLS+SYMBOLS).toList().shuffled()
    //println(pairs)
    println("Foram gerados ${SYMBOLS.length} pares aleatórios de símbolos.")
    println("Vamos jogar!")
    var places: List<Char> = allHiddenPairs(pairs)
    var trys = 0
    do {
        println("$trys: $places")
        val first = readPosition("primeira")
        val second = readPosition("segunda")
        if ( isValidPositions(first, second, places) ) {
            places = places.play(first, second, pairs)
            trys++
        } else println("Posições inválidas")
    } while( ! isAllPairsShowed(pairs, places) )
    println("$trys: $places")
    println("Terminou o jogo usando $trys tentativas")
}

/**
 * Flips the two elements at positions [p1] and [p2].
 * If they do not form a pair, display them for 4 seconds and then hide.
 * @receiver Original places
 * @param p1 First position to flip.
 * @param p2 Second position to flip.
 * @param pairs The original pairs
 * @return The turned places if there was a pair or the original places if not.
 */
fun List<Char>.play(p1: Int, p2: Int, pairs: List<Char>): List<Char> {
    val turned = turnPlaces(p1, p2, this, pairs)
    if (turned[p1] != turned[p2]) {
        print(turned)
        repeat(4) { print('.'); Thread.sleep(1000) }
        print("\r                                                       \r")
        return this
    }
    return turned
}

/**
 * Flips the elements into positions [p1] and [p2].
 * Showing them if they are hidden or hiding them if they are showing.
 * @receiver The current places
 * @param p1 A position to turn
 * @param p2 Another position to turn
 * @param pairs The original pairs
 * @return Places after turning
 */
//THIS IS THE WAY I HAD TO DO IT TO GET IT TO WORK
fun turnPlaces(p1: Int, p2: Int, pairs: List<Char>, places: List<Char>) : MutableList<Char>{

    val turned: MutableList<Char> = places.toMutableList()
    turned[p1] = pairs[p1]
    turned[p2] = pairs[p2]

    return turned
}

/**
 * Flips the elements into positions [p1] and [p2].
 * Showing them if they are hidden or hiding them if they are showing.
 * @receiver The current places
 * @param p1 A position to turn
 * @param p2 Another position to turn
 * @param pairs The original pairs
 * @return Places after turning
 */
//FIXED
fun turnPlaces(p1: Int, p2: Int, places: List<Char>, pairs: List< Char>): List< Char> {
    return places.mapIndexed{ i, place->
        if(i==p1) pairs[p1]
        else if(i==p2) pairs[p2]
        else place
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not giving you the answer since this looks like homework, but do you just want to return `places`, except with the items at indices `p1` and `p2` replaced with the corresponding items in `pairs`?

Here's a (kinda pointless) way of taking `places` and returning a new list containing each `place`:

```
places.mapIndexed { i, place ->
    place
}
```

But instead of just returning `place`, can you come up with an `if/else` condition that checks if the index `i` is one of the ones you're looking for, and returns the item from `pairs` instead?

---

By the way, your docstrings up there say `@receiver The current places`, are you supposed to be writing your functions like:

```
fun List<Char>.play(...)
```

and then calling them with `places.play()` etc? For the `play` function you're passing `places` in as a parameter as well, but you don't need to if it's the receiver. In that case you can access it with `this`

```
val turned = turnPlaces(p1, p2, pairs, this)
```

You can have it as a parameter if you prefer to have a named variable - but don't do both!

Comment: thanks, I did as you suggested and used the current instance instead of passing places as a parameter and managed to get the function working eventually as well.

Comment: @nuno Nice! If you want you can update your answer with what you did for the `mapIndexed` approach, and I'll tell you how I would have done it

Comment: Sure, I already updated it

Comment: @nuno yeah! You could also just do `if (i == p1 || i == p2) pairs[i] else place` since it doesn't matter which it is - you just need to check if `i` is one of those, and if so pull item `i` out of `pairs`. Thinking of it that way can help a lot if you have more things to check, since you could do things like `val specialIndices = listOf(p1, p2, p3, p4...)` and then check with `if (i in specialIndices) // do something with i`. Doesn't really matter here but it's a good general approach to remember!

Comment: Alright, I'll definitely keep it in mind, thanks!